# Insert a String to a spreadsheet cell using GDATA Objective C library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Im trying to insert a string value to a spreadsheet cell using  GDATA Objective C library. This is how I tried.

```
NSArray *entries = [mEntryFeed entries];
GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell *entry = [entries objectAtIndex:0];
GDataSpreadsheetCell *cell = [entry cell];
[cell setInputString:@"ABC"];
[cell setResultString:@"ABC"];
```

Problem is:
  This method does not update the google spreadsheet. How can I save the changes to actual spreadsheet? What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem

```
// Posting Changes
[service fetchFeedWithQuery:querySpreadsheet completionHandler:
    ^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error) {

        GDataEntrySpreadsheetCell *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:0];

        GDataSpreadsheetCell *cell = [entry cell];

        [cell setInputString:@"ABC"];

        //NSLog(@"FEED %@" , [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:0]);

        ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                          forFeedURL:feedURL
                                            delegate:nil
                                   didFinishSelector:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Does http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FSpreadsheetSample work for you ?

Comment: yes, it works. I can feed spreadsheets, worksheets and cell data. But I'm stuck in updating cell data.